# Incorrect syntax error when trying to insert into SQL Server using multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I am trying to insert into a table I created using multiple values. It throws error on incorrect syntax near coma in the first values line end.

I couldn't identify problem. I did try to insert separately, it inserted like a charm. Now I suspect the multi row inserting has some problem due to declared variable or `GETDATE` or both? It's not able to hold in session? I tried to put in transaction like begin tran and commit tran, still no luck. I have huge rows, any suggestions please?

```
DECLARE @USER VARCHAR(40)
SET @USER = SYSTEM_USER

INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, Name, User, Date)
VALUES (1, 'Cris', @USER, GETDATE()),
       (2, 'Joel', @USER, GETDATE()),
       (3, 'Kris', @USER, GETDATE());
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

However, no error when inserting separately using the declare statement in individual insert.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186101/discussion-on-question-by-learner-incorrect-syntax-error-when-trying-to-insert-i).

Answer (score 1):

The Issue is not with the Data But with your Column Names and the SQL Statement.

In SQL Server, there are certain System reserved Works which we call as **Keywords**. Usually, We don't entertain the use of these Keywords as Column Names since this may affect the Query Performance. The Column Names

> Name, User and Date

Are Keywords or Data Types in SQL Server, so while compiling the statements it will make confusions to the Compiler. So You Can solve this issue with either of the below 2 approaches :

**Approach# 1**

Change the Column Names which have the Same name as of the Keywords. You Can Identify this column easily by typing the COlumn Name in the SQL Server Management Studio and if the Text Color Changes to Blud, Pink or Gray ( Default Color Settings in SSMS) these are some system-defined Keywords

- Blue : Data Types
- Pink : System Defined Functions
- Gray : Keywords

*Please Note :*
Since changing the Column name will also cause issues with other Applications and you will have to change it in all those areas This approach is Less preferred if you already have a Stable system. But if you are just in the starting phase of your development then this will be a better way to solve future issues.

**Approach# 2**

This is the most easiest Idea, in all the places where you are using any of the systems reserved keywords listed above, put them inside Square brackets and this issue will be solved. This is the Quickest way to fix your issue

Your Updated Code should be like this :

```
DECLARE @USER VARCHAR(40)
SET @USER = SYSTEM_USER

INSERT INTO MyTable (Id, [Name], [User], [Date])
VALUES (1, 'Cris', @USER, GETDATE()),
       (2, 'Joel', @USER, GETDATE()),
       (3, 'Kris', @USER, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was insightful. As you rightly said, only one column in my actual case was in Blue and I used the bracket, still no luck. I literally found no issue in all the rows when I inserted individuall (Was a pain). I am clueless Where the HELL the problem is. Nobody in this post believe me, I didn't change any coma or anything, only thing is grouped insert said the error I posted while individual same rows inserted without any issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was insightful. As you rightly said, only one column in my actual case was in Blue and I used the bracket, still no luck. I literally found no issue in all the rows when I inserted individuall (Was a pain). I am clueless Where the HELL the problem is. Nobody in this post believe me, I didn't change any coma or anything, only thing is grouped insert said the error I posted while individual same rows inserted without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  I had other query tabs open in SSMS (v18.12.1) and had added records to tables with multiple values rows, in the following format, with no problems.

insert into dbo.MyTable (Field1, Field2, ... FieldN) values 
(value1, value2, ... valueN), 
(value1, value2, ... valueN), 
(value1, value2, ... valueN)

Yet, on this one tab, SSMS kept giving me the same error described by the OP.

I also followed the advice of verifying that I had no SQL key or special words as column names, but that did not help.

For me, the difference between the other tabs that worked, and this tab that did not, was that the other tabs had only a few rows (15+), and this tab had 500+ value rows.

I solved the problem by regrouping the commands to have a GO statement after each individual command, as in the following example.  I created my list of commands from a custom, command generator program, so it took only a little effort to refactor the code to follow the new format.

insert into dbo.MyTable (Field1, Field2, ... FieldN) values 
(value1, value2, ... valueN) -- row1 
GO

insert into dbo.MyTable (Field1, Field2, ... FieldN) values 
(value1, value2, ... valueN) -- row2 
GO

...

insert into dbo.MyTable (Field1, Field2, ... FieldN) values 
(value1, value2, ... valueN) -- rowN 
GO